# Highlighting image pick

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to ask for the user to pick image from severel images (direct display on screen).

How can i emphasis or perform some kind of Highligh showing the user what is his current pick?

Is there any view level attribute which can distinct the chosen view fom others?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have set background as a border of imageview and u also set image bitmap in src attribute.

**android:src="@drawable/imgicon"**

**android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner.xml"**

```
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/common_border_color" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <padding
            android:left="1dp"
            android:right="1dp"
            android:top="1dp" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

i hope its working fine..and Set margins of the image view 2dp from every side.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enlarge the current view.

```
your_view.setScaleX(1.5);
your_view.setScaleY(1.5);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScaleX(float)

Comment: Unfortunatly it requires api level 11 (my min is 8)

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you of a way of doing it.

**Steps:**

Make a relative layout, and put your image in that layout

Set margins of the image view 3dp from every side

When user selects an image, put some background image to the relative layout and it will actually become a selector

**Another way**

Another way of doing it is use `android animations`

Use Zoom in animation, and call it when ever a person selects an image, the image will actually zoom in the same image view